# Can we have WAMP Server and IIS(which has MYSQL and phpadmin) in same machine

Tags: php, mysql

To create a login form in Android, I installed WAMP server and tried to execute the program. But due to some access permission, the url didn't work outside PC. I tried changing the httpd.config to grant all permission and changed the url with IP address of my phone and WiFi, changed the firewall settings too.So I tried installing phpmyadmin and MYSQL in IIS for url access. When I install that, now WAMP server is not working in my PC too. The Apache, MySQL, PHP folder in C:wamp64 is missing. Can you please help me in this, whether its possible to have WAMP Server and phpmyadmin and MYSQL (installed in WPI) on the same machine. If not Can you please tell how to add php scripts to the IIS and what URL I have to give in android for accessing db.

Comment: yes its possible to have Wamp and IIS on the same machine, but you have to change the port if you want to run both server at same time on same machine.

Comment: The ports (plural) actually, at least if you intend to run two instances of mysql as well.

Comment: The port no for WAMP is 80 and IIS is 8080.how Can you help in this.Because once I installed PHPadmin in IIS,the one I has in WAMP server doesnot Exists,Can I uninstal and reinstal WAMP now.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add php scripts in IIS to access it in online